# Action Bar can not be seen when applying @style/Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar in Manifest.xml

Tags: android, xml, themes, android-manifest, material-design

I am a starter in Android field ,to get the UI score from my teacher,I want to have the Material Design effect on devices under 5.0 ,so I add Android-support-V7-appcompat as the lib of my project.

And After that I change the Manifest.xml:Theme:@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar but with this action I still can not see any Actionbar.

I delete this theme setting and then the actionbar appears with the theme of Holo,how can I fix it?

The **setting.activity** which I want to have the appearance of Material Design

```
  package scm.chenhyuan2.RightSpeed;

  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.content.Intent;
  import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.util.Log;
  import android.view.Menu;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
  import android.widget.Button;

  public class SettingActivity extends Activity {

private static final String LOG_TAG = "SettingActivity";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.setting);

    Button mStartButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);
    mStartButton.getBackground().setColorFilter(0x8000FF00, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
    mStartButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(SettingActivity.this, RunningCadenceActivity.class));
        }
    });


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // It will only be called when returns from PreferenceActivity.
    // Restart to load in new locale in case it's changed by user.
    restartActivity();
}

private void restartActivity() {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Restart activity");
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    finish();
    startActivity(intent);
}

  }
```

The **setting.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <com.gc.materialdesign.views.ButtonFloat
                android:id="@+id/button00"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_margin="3dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/target_cadence"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <kankan.wheel.widget.WheelView
        android:id="@+id/targetCadence"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/steps_per_minute"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/startButton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/start"
        android:textColor="#D0D0D0"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And finally the Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="scm.chenhyuan2.RightSpeed"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="assignment2" >
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name="scm.chenhyuan2.RightSpeed.Application" android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

        <activity android:name="scm.chenhyuan2.RightSpeed.SettingActivity" > 
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:name="scm.chenhyuan2.RightSpeed.RunningCadenceActivity" />

        <activity android:name="scm.chenhyuan2.RightSpeed.PreferenceActivity" />

        <service android:name="scm.chenhyuan2.RightSpeed.BackgroundService" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to use `appcompat-v7`, you have to inherit from `ActionBarActivity`, not `Activity`.

Comment: I tried to edit the  `public class SettingActivity extends Activity` to `public class SettingActivity extends ActionBarActivity` directly in the settingactivity.java but there are lots of red cross appeared, the eclipse suggest me to change to androidbar.app.What's the right way to do it?should I recreate the whole .java file?

Comment: @StevenYUAN: "but there are lots of red cross appeared" -- did you add the corresponding `import` statement?

Comment: I tried to use the control+shift+o to automatically import but nothing happens. manully add import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity still not works.

Comment: @StevenYUAN: Then something is wrong in how you have attached the `appcompat-v7` library to your project. There is not much I can do to help you with that, though [here is a directory of Android Studio-compatible projects](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/AppCompat) that all use `appcompat-v7`, if that is useful.

Comment: Finally I fixed it.The property setting of the project lose two .jar file even when I follow all the instructions to import it,I just add external jar file~then it works.Thanks a lot as well